# how to compare the current date with given date(without time) in velocity

Tags: velocity

I want to compare the current date with the given date(without time) in velocity. how to get the current date without time and compare the same with existing one.

please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It you use VelocityTools, $date contains a DateTool.

Then, if $foo contains the date to test, what about:

```
#if("$date.year/$date.month/$date.day" == "$foo.year/$foo.month/$foo.day")
...
#end
```

Otherwise, we need some more informations on how you are using Velocity.

Comment: Thanks  Claude Brisson.